# Translating a Contact Form's placeholders / JQuery / JavaScript / Contact Form

Tags: javascript, json, contact-form

**Hello,**

I've written a multilanguage website using jquery and localStorage. The translator works perfect. There are no bugs.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arrLang = {
      'pl': {
        'home': 'Strona główna',
        'about': 'O nas',
        'contact': 'Kontakt',
        'gallery': 'Galeria',
        'callnow': 'Zadzwoń teraz i umów przeprowadzkę!'
      },
      'en': {
        'home': 'Home',
        'about': 'About',
        'contact': 'Contact',
        'gallery': 'Gallery',
        'callnow': 'Call now and sign up!'
      }
    };

    function translateLang(lang) {
        $('.lang').each(function(index, item) {
          $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
        });
    };

    $(function() {
        //first check for stored language in localStorage i.e. fetch data from localStorage
        let stored_lang = localStorage.getItem("stored_lang");
        //if any then translate page accordingly
        if(stored_lang != null && stored_lang != undefined)
        {
            lang = stored_lang;
            translateLang(lang);
        }


      $('.translate').click(function() {
        var lang = $(this).attr('id');
         //on click store language to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("stored_lang",lang);
        translateLang(lang);
      });

    });
</script>




<button id="pl" class="translate">Polski</button>
<button id="en" class="translate">English</button>
<nav class="header-bottom-left">
    <ul>
        <a href="index.php#indexmain"><li class="lang" key="home">Strona główna</li></a>
        <a href="about.php#indexabout"><li class="lang" key="about">O nas</li></a>
        <a href="gallery.php#indexgallery"><li class="lang" key="gallery">Galeria</li></a>
        <a href="contact.php#indexcontact"><li class="lang" key="contact">Kontakt</li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Now I'm having a problem with translating a Contact Form's placeholders. I figured out to use JavaScript document.getElementById('id').placeholder='string'; and it works just great, but the data isn't being saved in localStorage and after the refresh of the site it's showing the basic strings again. I also changed  on my translator buttons to  so don't be confused about my code above.

```
      <div class="contact-form-container">
            <div class="contact-form">
                <form id="contact-form" action="contact-form-handler.php" method="POST">
                    <p class="lang" key="contact-form" style="margin: 0 auto; font-size: 22px; font-family: Open Sans; color: #ff4800; margin-bottom: 8px;">Formularz kontaktowy</p>
                    <div class="flex-break"></div>
                    <input id="contact-form-name" class="contact-form-content" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Imię" required><div class="flex-break"></div>
                    <input id="contact-form-email" class="contact-form-content" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required><div class="flex-break"></div>
                    <input id="contact-form-topic" class="contact-form-content" type="text" name="topic" placeholder="Temat" required><div class="flex-break"></div>
                    <!-- <select style="flex-basis:12%; padding: 6px;" class="contact-form-content" id="prefix" name="whereFromPrefix">
                        <option value="ul.">ul.</option>
                        <option value="os.">os.</option>
                        <option value=" "></option>
                    </select>
                    <input style="flex-basis:67%;" class="contact-form-content" type="text" name="whereFrom" placeholder="Skąd? Adres, Miasto"><div class="flex-break"></div>
                    <select style="flex-basis:12%; padding: 6px; margin-bottom: 12px;" class="contact-form-content" id="prefix" name="whereToPrefix">
                        <option value="ul.">ul.</option>
                        <option value="os.">os.</option>
                        <option value=" "></option>
                    </select>
                    <input style="flex-basis:67%; margin-bottom: 12px;" class="contact-form-content" type="text" name="whereTo" placeholder="Dokąd? Adres, Miasto"><div class="flex-break"></div> -->
                    <textarea id="contact-form-text" style="line-height:16px; font-size: 14px; font-family: calibri;" class="contact-form-content" name="message" id="contact-form-message" cols="" rows="10" placeholder="Dodatkowe informacje"></textarea>
                    <div class="flex-break"></div>
                    <button class="contact-form-content-submit" name="submit" type="submit">Wyślij<img id ="Contact_icon_white" src="img/Contact_icon_white.png" alt="White contact icon"></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>



<div class="header-top-right-translate">
                    <div id="pl" class="translate translate-button"><p onclick="
                        document.getElementById('contact-form-name').placeholder='Imię';
                        document.getElementById('contact-form-email').placeholder='E-mail';
                        document.getElementById('contact-form-topic').placeholder='Temat';
                        document.getElementById('contact-form-text').placeholder='Dodatkowe informacje';
                    ">Polski</p></div>

                    <div><p style="opacity: 0.7; font-size: 12px;">|</p></div>

                    <div id="en" class="translate translate-button"><p onclick="
                        document.getElementById('contact-form-name').placeholder='Name';
                        document.getElementById('contact-form-email').placeholder='E-mail';
                        document.getElementById('contact-form-topic').placeholder='Topic';
                        document.getElementById('contact-form-text').placeholder='More information';
                    ">English</p></div>
        
                </div>
```

Can someone tell me how to change the placeholders inside Contact Form but to not lose them after refreshing the site?

Comment: I tested your code and only made some minor tweaks: I added the class lang and attr key to the input fields, added their data to the arrLang and added `$(this).prop("placeholder",arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);` to change the placeholders and it works, and the localstorage is retained on page reload.

Comment: Can you tell me where and how should I insert your code? $(this).prop("placeholder",arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);